# shell script: integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
if [$# -ne 1];
then
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
else if [$1 ='a'];
then
  echo "b"
else if [$1 ='b']; then
  echo "a"
else 
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
fi
```

I'm getting below error while run above script in Linux.

```
bar.sh: line 2: [: S#: integer expression expected
a
```

Could you please help to remove this error?

Comment: Gee, I *do* hope you are not practicing your shell scripting in the root account.

Comment: The `S#` in the error message looks like you misspelled `$#` either when transcribing the error message or in the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
if [$# -ne 1];
```

`[` and `]` requires spacing. Example:

```
if [ $# -ne 1 ];
```

And `else if` should be `elif`

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ];
then
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
elif [ "$1" ='a' ];
then
  echo "b"
elif [ "$1" ='b' ]; then
  echo "a"
else
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
fi
```

Do not forget to quote variables. It is not every time necessary, but recommended.

Question: Why do i have -1?

Comment: The semicolons after the `]`s are only necessary if you put the `then` on the same line.

Comment: I know, but this is no problem so i did not change it.

Comment: Doh! I didn't notice that that was how it was in the original script.

Comment: You also need spaces around the operators (including after the `=`) inside `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't allow `else if`. Instead, use `elif`.

Also, you need spacing within your `[...]` expression.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ];
then
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
elif [ $1 ='a' ];
then
  echo "b"
elif [ $1 ='b' ]; then
  echo "a"
else 
  echo "/root/script.sh a|b"
fi
```